# Why use DOCUMENT_ROOT instead of defining the required path?

Tags: php, path, document-root

Just a thought but it occurred to me that when I wanted to define the document root for a website that I could use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and it works fine on a live host.

Then I thought why not just use a simple:

```
define('SITEPATH,'http://www.site.co.uk');
```

The define method works fine with no need to use document root.

Am I missing something? Or is it just a matter or personal preference?

Answer (score 0):

Because the SITEPATH allow you to create URL.

But when you want include another PHP file you need a system path to do that.

Comment: Hi Jedema,thanks for the reply. Not too sure I understand. So you are saying I can't use a defined path as part of a php include, is that correct? Thanks

Comment: No, sorry for confusing. I want to say both can be usefull : 
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."include/db.php");
    <a href="<?php echo SITEPATH;?>/module1/page.php">link</a>

We must just use these in the good situation.

Comment: You're welcome it was a pleasure.
Don't forget check question is fixed ;)